# Struggling to find good Examples of iOS app clip & Android instant Apps

Tags: google-play, app-store, android-instant-apps, apple-appclips

I've searched for examples of [iOS app clip](https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/) & [Android instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant) but could not find more than few examples.
I am looking for released apps in App Store/Google Play or open source examples.
good examples could make developing these new features easier and gives developers new creative ideas to use these wonderful tools.

- Do you have an app that utilizes App clip or instant app?
- How did this affect your app?
- What is the challenges you have faced?

Note: I know this is not a typical question but it need to be asked in a community full of great developers who love to share knowledge with others, and I don't think there is a better place than here.

[image: App clip]   [image: instant app]

Answer (score 0):

**Intro**
I know it's been 10 months since you posted the question but I just stumbled upon it now... I've developed an app called ARShades for both iOS and Android that allows the user to try glasses on via Augmented Reality and I'm still in charge of development. The app supports both Instant App and App Clip, although I'm facing troubles making the the app banner show for the App Clip.

**Firebase issues**
As far as I can tell developing App Clips is a tad harder than develeloping Instant Apps, I'll tell you why. The main apps for both systems make extensive use of Firebase Firestore and many other features. This isn't a problem on Android where sockets are supported across the board, while on iOS they are only supported in the main app, so I had to use REST API to read and write data on Firebase when developing the App Clip, it's been a nightmare since it was the first time for me dealing with REST APIs (I just finished yesterday and published the update).

**App Size**
Another issue I faced is related to reducing the app size. On Android I had to remove all the unused images and compress the remamining ones. On iOS I had to separate the asset catalogues between: used only by the main app, shared, and used only by app clip. And of course I went through some compression works there too. I forgot to mention that I developed a new app as Instant App on Android, while you cannot do the same on iOS since it **must** be in the same project.

**App to site linking**
Another insidious part was the linking of the site to the apps. I managed to do it on Android by making changes to the manifest and specifying the host, while I can't seem to find a way to link the App Clip to the site in ay way. I've done everything the documentation says. I've put the apple app site association file in the .well-known folder but nothing, no banner shows up. I'll keep working on that.
Edit: Everything is now solved.

**Conclusions**
So, to sum up, I've found Instant Apps better on the developing and hassle side of things, they support sockets, hence the full suite of frameworks the full apps have. I hope I kind of answered your question, although I think you have documented yorself elsewhere in these past 10 months XD

Links to Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.spaarkly.arshades&hl=en_US&gl=US

Link to iOS: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/arshades-demo/id1586661818

Link for trying [Instant App / App Clip](https://spaarkly.page.link/?link=https://www.safilo.arshades.it/PLD7045S.html?c%3DrBf3geYISXtkue0WGgFT%26m%3DyZbjAfqr9cSzj9JaVKxT&apn=it.spaarkly.arshades&afl=https://www.safilo.arshades.it/PLD7045S.html?c%3DrBf3geYISXtkue0WGgFT%26m%3DyZbjAfqr9cSzj9JaVKxT&isi=1586661818&ibi=it.spaarkly.ARShades-demo&ifl=https://safilo.arshades.it/PLD7045S.html?c=rBf3geYISXtkue0WGgFT%26m=yZbjAfqr9cSzj9JaVKxT/&efr=1)

Comment: Wall of text... Better break it down.

Comment: Ok, I just did it.